# boost::is_same with templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm puzzled by the following problem. I want to write some trait struct in order to test if a certain class is derived from another. This can be solved with boost::is_base_of<>. However, the base class I want to test against has a free undefined template parameter.

Here is some code example:

```
template<typename T> class Base {};

class IntDeriv : Base<int> {};

class Foo {};

template< class TestClass >
struct is_derived_from_Base {
   // how to create something that does the following and forces the compiler to deduce T
   static const bool value = boost::is_base_of< Base<T> , TestClass >::value;
};

int main() {
    cout << is_derived_from_Base<Foo> << endl;         // should print 0
    cout << is_derived_from_Base<IntDeriv> << endl;    // should print 1
}
```

The problem is how to deduce `T` for `Base<T>` inside `is_base_of`.
Is this possible at all? I smell some enable_if but I'm not sure how to put it together.

Comment: Yes, that was also my first guess. However, there are several similar problems that can be solved with some enable_if/SFINAE magic. The point is that the compiler has actually no need to deduce T. I just want to know if some class is derived from Base for some arbitrary T.

Comment: @jrok That is possible, see my answer. Note that the method can be extended to find the type of the base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is possible. The trick used is possible in C++03, but as you didn't specify I will give you the C++11 version (using `decltype`, not available in C++03):

```
template<class TestClass>
struct is_derived_from_Base
{
    template<typename T>
    static std::true_type inherited(Base<T>*);
    static std::false_type inherited(void*);

    static const bool value = decltype(inherited(new TestClass()))::value;
};
```

You can see a [live version here](http://ideone.com/xaerUH).

So, how does it works ?

When the struct is instantiated and `value` is needed, the compiler will get the return type of `inherited(new TestClass())`. This will call the appropriate function: if `TestClass` inherits `Base<T>`, then `TestClass*` (returned by `new`) is castable to `Base<T>*`, `T` being automatically deduced by the compiler. The return type is `std::true_type`. If `TestClass` does not inherits `Base<T>`, then the other overload is choosen, and the return type is `std::false_type`. The rest is straightforward: `std::true_type::value = true` and `std::false_type::value = false`.

There are still some corner cases:

- Using private inheritance results in a compile error. I do not know how to solve it, because I don't know the answer: if A privately inherits B, is A derived from B or not ? (in general, private inheritance is considered as an implementation inheritance). Also note that in this case, `A* a = new B();` will not compile.
- Using a private constructor prevents the previously explained trick from working correctly. It will result in a compile-time error. Since this defeats the whole point of this method, you will have to find another way for such classes.

*Note you have to use it the following way: `is_derived_from_Base<Foo>::value`, not as you've written (`is_derived_from_Base<Foo>`).*

Comment: Awesome. Makes perfect sense. I was drifting in that direction (using some function overloading thingy) but did not see that solution. Thanks a lot.